# Exchanging messages/objects through socket in language independent way

Tags: java, serialization, soa

I'm looking for a library or a small framework that allow to exchange objects between a java service application and a front end application written in another language such as PHP, C# or even C++ .

The java service(server) that reside on an embedded device, should send and receive objects with its clients that could be written in Java, C#, PHP or C++.

I'm looking for a small and lightweight library or framework that allow to exchange messages and objects between client and server using a socket connection.

I saw for example [WOX serializer](http://woxserializer.sourceforge.net/) that can serialize objects in language independent way but only between C# and Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JSON.  (Seriously, JSON and YAML are about the best choices for language-independent serialization; JSON is more portable but has less features, so start there, and step to YAML if you must.)

Comment: Does exist some library that automate serialization/deserialization with JSON/YAML ? Something like WOX in the example ...

Comment: Absolutely, but not *a* library that covers all your named languages (that I know of); see [the list at json.org](http://www.json.org/) which links to libraries for every language under the sun ^W^W that you named.